# Not getting output on Kibana when sending filebeat data to logstash

Tags: logstash, kibana, filebeat

I am sending a csv file using filebeat to logstash

**filebeat.yml**

```
filebeat.inputs:
- input_type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - 'C:/Users/Sarwar Khan/Desktop/*csv'
fields:
  type: test_log_csv
fields_under_root: true
```

## ------------------------------ Logstash Output -------------------------------

```
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
  enabled: true
#output.elasticsearch:
  #hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
```

**AND BELOW ARE MY LOGSTASH conf file details**

```
input{
beats{
type => "log"
port => "5044"
}
}
filter{
}
output{
elasticsearch{
   hosts=> ["http://localhost:9200/"]
   index=> "updatedlogs"
}
stdout{codec => rubydebug}
}
```

I checked the configuration of both the files and it is shown to be Ok

when I use command in bin folder of logstash ".\logstash.bat -f logstash.conf"

shows the message of pipeline running and starting server on port:5044, but it remains the same for an infinite time

```
[2021-05-23T11:34:54,110][INFO ][logstash.agent] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2021-05-23T11:34:54,174][INFO ][org.logstash.beats.Server][main][2496bea2569a0e624066c2a0c9b99694a3ea677bbd5bbd2ee5aa73176e42fef0] Starting server on port: 5044
```

Comment: Did you try to set up elastic search as an output for filebeat? Did you try to set logstash output to `stdout `? Just to determine where is the issue, filebeat, logstash or elastic.

Comment: filebeat.yml content
# ---------------------------- Elasticsearch Output ----------------------------
#output.elasticsearch:
  #hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]

Below is my logstash config file:
input{
beats{
type => "log"
port => "5044"
}
}
filter{
}
output{
elasticsearch{
   hosts=> ["http://localhost:9200/"]
   index=> "updatedlogs"
}
stdout{codec => rubydebug}
}

Comment: is filebeat running? Also regarding filebeat, how does it deals with file that has already been read (because I saw similar issues with the logstash file input)?

Comment: @baudsp thanks you are right, the data was already read so it was not reading further, when I added more data it worked fine